# Merge two dataframes on a third dataframe that links the two

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I don't know how to phrase this well, but I have three dataframes in R. One with first names and kill score, one with last names and killscore, and one with first- and lastname. I want to combine the first dataframe with the second dataframe based on the third dataframe like:

```
kills1
     [,1]    [,2]
[1,] "Matt"  "5" 
[2,] "John"  "6" 
[3,] "Chris" "4

kills2
     [,1]    [,2]
[1,] "Wick"  "10"
[2,] "Damon" "3" 
[3,] "Rock"  "9" 

 fullnames
     [,1]    [,2]   
[1,] "John"  "Wick" 
[2,] "Matt"  "Damon"
[3,] "Chris" "Rock"
```

Desired output

```
allkills
     [,1]         [,2] [,3]
[1,] "John Wick"  "6"  "10"
[2,] "Matt Damon" "5"  "3" 
[3,] "chris Rock" "4"  "9"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider two `merge` with each column of 'fullnames' to 'kills1' and 'kills2' first column (after converting the `matrix` to `data.frame`

```
out1 <- merge(as.data.frame(fullnames), as.data.frame(kills2),
        by.x = 'V2', by.y = 'V1')
out1 <- merge(out1, as.data.frame(kills1), by.x = 'V1', by.y = 'V1')
```